# Redirect 301 not working for all pages on Apache

Tags: apache, .htaccess, redirect

I've already looked at many samples and tutorials how to set up those 301 redirects on Apache and can't figure out why only the second one is working:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

#doesn't work:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com$
RewriteRule ^page-still-exists.htm$ "http://www.new.com/new-target-page.htm" [R=301,L]

#works:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com$
RewriteRule ^page-does-no-longer-exist.htm$ "http://www.new.com/" [R=301,L]

#works:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com$
RewriteRule ^folder/otherpage.htm$ "http://www.new.com/" [R=301,L]

#works:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http://www.new.com/" [R=301,L]

#doesn't work:
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.old.com$
RewriteRule ^somepage.htm$ "http://www.old.com/some-page.htm" [R=301,L]
```

I have no idea why only the second one is working. The only difference I can see is, that in the second case the old page does no longer exist on the old domain. But whenever I want to redirect any still existing page from the old domain to the new domain the page on the old domain is still used.

Any input is much appreciated because this is slowly driving me crazy :)

**EDIT:** I added the complete htaccess file.

**EDIT 2:** So I removed almost all redirects and currently my htaccess looks like this:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^old\.com$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.old\.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ "http\:\/\/www\.new\.com\/$1" [R=301,L]
```

The only redirect that is working is the simple one from old.com to new.com. A redirect like old.com/page.htm to new.com or even new.com/page.htm is not working. And actually I really don't know where this redirect is actually coming from... Can a 301 really be so complicated?

Comment: Is this the only rule or you have more rules?

Comment: Yes, there are some other RewriteRules present in the same way and one rule to redirect the index page to the new domain.

Comment: Can you edit your question and post your complete .htaccess?

Comment: @anubhava The question contains the complete htaccess file now. Thanks for taking a look!

Comment: This question has also been asked here: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/64841/htaccess-cpanel-301-redirects-not-working-for-add-on-domain

Answer (score 0):

Can you try just this rule and see how it behaves:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^page-still-exists\.htm$ http://www.new.com/new-target-page.htm [R=301,L,NC]
```

Comment: Unfotrunately no luck. The old page is still not redirected to the new domain :(

Comment: If this is the only rule in your root .htaccess then I suspect you have some rule in your Apache config.

Comment: Well, the old.com domain is an add-on domain to some other domain. Does the .htaccess of the "main" domain has any impact on the behaviour?

Comment: No it should not since we have `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?old\.com$ [NC]` condition

Comment: But what kind of configuration could it be that prevents the page to be redirected and where can I find the config files? Maybe also somewhere in the cPanel settings? Unfortunately I'm not an Apache expert...

Comment: Not configuration but there can be real rewrite rules in Apache config files.

Comment: @anubhava: With the way add-on domains are usually setup in cPanel/Apache (pointing to a subdirectory) the .htaccess of the "main" domain **can** have an impact on the behaviour of the add-on domain since the .htaccess of the main domain is processed first (since it is in the parent directory on the file system).

Comment: @w3d: If `DocumentRoot` of add-on domain is correctly set to a sub directory then main domain's .htaccess won't be used at all.

Comment: @anubhava: Even if the `DocumentRoot` of the add-on domain is set correctly (to a subdirectory off the main accounts document root) the main domain's .htaccess (in the parent directory) is still processed first.

Comment: @w3d: That is actually not true. I didn't respond immediately because I wanted to verify it on my Apache first. Since I am doing `RewriteEngine On` again in add-on domain's .htaccess and **not using** `RewriteOptions Inherit` anywhere basically means only this current add-on domain's .htaccess will be processed leaving aside parent domain's .htaccess.

Comment: @anubhava: Thanks for getting back. Sorry, yes, you are _partially_ correct. However, this only seems to apply to mod_rewrite. mod_rewrite directives in the parent domain's .htaccess file are indeed not processed (unless `RewriteOptions inherit` is set in the addon domain's .htaccess). However, the parent domain's .htaccess itself _is_ processed, including any mod_alias, mod_env directives etc - so this could have an impact on the addon domain. (Aside: not sure why this is different to a subdomain - mod_rewrite directives in the parent .htaccess **do** get processed in this instance!?)

Comment: (Aside: Correction to last part of above comment... it's the same for a subdomain _if_ you are using mod_rewrite ie. `RewriteEngine On` in the subdomains .htaccess file.)

Comment: Yes that is right. Since this question was all about `mod_rewrite` I was also talking about rewrite rules only.